# AGM battery float voltage

Tags: chemical-engineering, battery

It is a fact that AGM batteries are typically charged with higher voltages, compared to the other lead-acid batteries (flooded and GEL).

I don't understand the reason for this, is it related to the cell manufacturing? (Since the chemical reactions should be the same for all lead-acid batteries)

Moreover, since AGM batteries are pretty sensitive to overcharging, the fact of using higher charging voltages seem to me even counterintuitive